# load-spark-env.sh, spark-submit: no such file or directory

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to install apache-spark on my iMac, using the instructions on these 2 pages:

https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-install-apache-pyspark-on-macbook-pro-4a9249f0d823

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/installing-scala-and-apache-spark-on-mac-os-837ae57d283f/

During installation, I couldn't run

> brew cask install java

so instead I ran

> brew install java

I think I managed to install everything, including apache-spark. But when I ran the commands spark-shell or pyspark, I keep running into the following errors:

For spark-shell:

> /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin/spark-shell: line 60: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexecexport/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory

For pyspark:

> /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin/pyspark: line 24: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexecexport/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
> /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin/pyspark: line 68: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexecexport/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
> /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin/pyspark: line 68: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexecexport/bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory

My iMac is running Big Sur version 11.1. Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't have JDK installed. After installing JDK, the problem is resolved.